# White screen of death when narrowing window on MVC project

Tags: user-interface, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

Thanks in advance for your time.

My company project uses kendo UI and kendo.bootstrap for UI/X design, but the problem is the decision they tought to use Bootstrap modal too.

So it is a mess in there and js's overlap like crazy.

But I saw one page when I narrow page It gets completely blank.In responsive mode

Any ideas?!

Thanks

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your posts.

Answer (score 1):

There's your problem:

`js's overlap like crazy`

If you have one page blanking now, you'll have tons and tons of other weird, unpredictable errors in the future. Sort it out **now**.

Follow this official Kendo guide: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap

When a page is blanking, **the first thing to do** is to check the [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: As I just realized that error happen in responsive mode I can't thank you enough You are right It must be kendo fighting bootstrap.

Comment: first thing first I will check JavaScriptConsole